# Why would the prae­po­si­tion "per" ever take an ab­la­tive in­stead of an ac­cu­sa­tive com­ple­ment?

Tags: classical-latin, language-evolution, preposition, ablative, accusative

## *PER* + ABL.: Bar­bar­ism, solœ­­cism, or di­a­chron­ic evo­lu­tion?

*Lewis and Short* clear­ly state that *per* is a prae­po­si­tion whose
nor­mal com­ple­ment is in the ac­cusative. With­out hav­ing dol­ven too
deeply in­to dusty cor­po­ra of lim­it­ed search ca­pa­bil­i­ty, all
ex­am­ples I’ve so far chanced up­on, how­so­ev­er ar­bi­trar­i­ly
scat­tered and there­fore ir­rep­re­sen­ta­tive­ly anec­do­tal,
nonethe­less uni­ver­sal­ly em­ploy the ac­cusative for all of *per*’s com­ple­men­ta­tion.

How­ev­er, [L&S fur­ther
men­tion](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dper1),
al­be­it par­en­thet­i­cal­ly, that “by so­le­cism” *per* can some­times be
found to take an ab­la­tive com­ple­ment, viz.:

> **per**, prep. with acc. (by sole­cism with abl. PER QVO, =

Is the su­per­cit­ed “so­le­cism” say­ing that if you’re us­ing ab­la­tive,
you have no rea­son to both­er with an ex­plic­it prae­po­si­tion in the
first place?

In book 2 of *The Æ­ne­id* start­ing at line 210, Vir­gil has *with/by blood and
fire* in the ab­la­tive with­out both­er­ing to dec­o­rate these with a ple­o­nas­tic
prae­po­si­tion:

> *Fit so­ni­tus spu­man­te sa­lo; iam­que ar­va te­ne­bant,
>
> ar­den­tis­que ocu­los suf­fec­ti **san­gui­ne et ig­ni**,
>
> si­bi­la lam­be­bant lin­guis vi­bran­ti­bus ora.*

I can read­i­ly un­earth un­count­ably many ex­am­ples of ven­er­at­ed
writ­ers us­ing *per* nev­er with the ab­la­tive, on­ly with the
ac­cusative alone. My read­ing of the [OED’s first two sub­sens­es for
*so­le­cism*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/184132?redirectedFrom=solecisms#eid)
sug­gest that they are equat­ing *so­le­cism* with *cat­a­chre­sis*:

> 1. **a.** An im­pro­pri­ety or ir­reg­u­lar­i­ty in speech or dic­tion; a
>    vi­o­la­tion of the rules of gram­mar or syn­tax; prop­er­ly, a faul­ty
>    con­cord.

> **b.** With­out ar­ti­cle: Vi­o­la­tion of the rules of con­cord in
> gram­mar or syn­tax; in­cor­rect or un­gram­mat­i­cal speech or dic­tion,
> or the use of this.

Shall I as­sume that giv­ing *per* an ab­la­tive com­ple­ment is to be
con­sid­ered stig­mat­ic of one or an­oth­er sort of faulty gram­mar,
wheth­er per­ceived to come from un­let­tered rus­tics who are pre­sumed to
know no bet­ter, or as some de­spec­tive ne­ol­o­gism in­vent­ed by new­er
gen­er­a­tions fur­ther along the Sis­y­phe­an pen­du­lum swing­ing from
Clas­si­cal Lat­in’s high­ly syn­thet­ic mod­el to­wards the some­what more
an­a­lyt­ic mod­el of Pro­to- and even­tu­al­ly Mod­ern Ro­mance?

Comment: Welcome to the site and thank you for an interesting question! A small remark: L&S seems to imply that *per* means the same thing with either case (as nothing else is mentioned). Therefore even with ablative *per* seems to have an effect on meaning.

Comment: +1 While *per* + accusative can sometimes have a meaning similar to the bare ablative, this is often not the case. In addition, the bare ablative is unusual with people, at least in classical prose, so that wouldn't be an option anyway in those cases. // I believe I have seen *per* + ablative on occasion in post-classical Latin, which would make it a soloecism...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The L&S entry is pretty clear, in my opinion. *Per* takes the accusative, but it has mistakenly been used with the ablative. It cites two examples from later inscriptions:

- Inscr. Miseni Repert. ex a. p. Chr. n. 159
- Inscr. Orell. 3300

After some tracking down, I found it in [*Campania tardoantica (284-604 d.C.)*](https://books.google.com/books?id=L07S3aMJLMgC&pg=PA283&lpg=PA283). Here is a relevant image from pg. 283:

[image: inscription]

Answer (score 1):

Francesco Cavalli called the mass he wrote in 1675 ***Missa pro defunctis per octo vocibus*** and that's still the name by which we know it. No doubt it should read "Missa pro defunctis octo vocibus", where *octo vocibus* is in the dative.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for the answer! Should *octo vocibus* after *per* be construed as ablative or dative? Both make some sense but neither seems classically grammatical.

Comment: Perhaps *per* was a mistranscription of a second *pro*?